# Laravel nova, "call to function tap() on null"

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

- Laravel version: 8.12
- Nova version: 3.22.0
- PHP version: 7.4.2
- Webserver `artisan serve`

It feels like I'm missing something essential in Laravel Nova.
I have two models and i want them as Nova resources with a relationship between them. They models are called "Template" and "Asset" where one "Template" hasMany "Assets".

There is no logic in the models, just two simple models with simple resources such as text fields.

When i view or edit a template i get:

```
"message": "Call to a member function tap() on null",
    "exception": "Error",
    "file": "laravel\\nova\\src\\Query\\Builder.php",
    "line": 265,
```

And it looks like this:
[image: Nova Error, tap() on null]
I have tried:

- Recreate the models and assets with different names.
- I `php artisan clear:cache` and `composer dump` between every change.
- I created a new model + resource and attached to the user model/resource instead, that worked like expected. So i compared user with template but i didnt find anything different (except user being Authenticatable)
- Removed and reinstalled vendor folder.
- Cleaned away any unused code

**Template model (Models/Template.php):**

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Template extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $casts = [
        'published_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function assets() {        
        $this->hasMany(Asset::class);
    }
}
```

**Template resource (Nova/Template.php):**

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
//use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Image;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\DateTime;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\HasMany;

class Template extends Resource
{
    public static $model = \App\Models\Template::class;

    public static $title = 'title';

    public static $search = [
        'title',
    ];

    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('Title'),
            Text::make('Slug'),
            Text::make('Content'),
            //Image::make(__('Featured Image')),
            DateTime::make('Will be published at', "published_at")->format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"),
            Text::make('Source'),
            Text::make('Composition'),
            HasMany::make('Assets')
        ];
    }

    public function cards(Request $request){
        return [];
    }

    public function filters(Request $request){
        return [];
    }

    public function lenses(Request $request){
        return [];
    }
    public function actions(Request $request){
        return [];
    }
}
```

**The Asset model (Models/Asset.php):**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Asset extends Model
{
    public function template() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Template::class);
    }
}
```

**And the Asset resource (Noca/Asset.php):**

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\BelongsTo;

class Asset extends Resource
{

    public static $model = \App\Models\Asset::class;

    public static $title = 'id';

    public static $search = [
        'id',
    ];


    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('Property', 'property'),
            Text::make('Value', 'value'),
            BelongsTo::make('Template')
        ];
    }

    public function cards(Request $request){
        return [];
    }

    public function filters(Request $request){
        return [];
    }

    public function lenses(Request $request){
        return [];
    }

    public function actions(Request $request){
        return [];
    }
}
```

But I still get the same error. I'm soon going crazy, and many hours have been put into this one.

What am I missing?

Full trace:

```
"trace": [
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\nova\\src\\Query\\Builder.php",
            "line": 196,
            "function": "applyQueryCallbacks",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Query\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\nova\\src\\Http\\Requests\\ResourceIndexRequest.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "paginate",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Query\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\nova\\src\\Http\\Controllers\\ResourceIndexController.php",
            "line": 20,
            "function": "searchIndex",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Requests\\ResourceIndexRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Controllers\\ResourceIndexController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 254,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 197,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 693,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\nova\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\Authorize.php",
            "line": 18,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\Authorize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\nova\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\BootTools.php",
            "line": 20,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\BootTools",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\nova\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\DispatchServingNovaEvent.php",
            "line": 20,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\DispatchServingNovaEvent",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 50,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php",
            "line": 44,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\nova\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php",
            "line": 78,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
            "line": 121,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
            "line": 64,
            "function": "handleStatefulRequest",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php",
            "line": 67,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 695,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 670,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 636,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 625,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 166,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\nova\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\ServeNova.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\ServeNova",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 110,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "D:\\kod\\project\\laravel\\server.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 9):

This was so easy, I forgot to **return** the hasMany relation from the Template model.

```
    public function assets() {        
        $this->hasMany(Asset::class);
    }
```

Should be:

```
    public function assets() {        
        return $this->hasMany(Asset::class);
    }
```